# Simplifying polynomial Roots with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, assumptions

I have acquired the following root from a minimization problem:

```
Root[1 + 2/(1 - 2 p)^4 - 3/(1 - 2 p)^2 - 4 p + 4 p^2 - 
   16 Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(-1 + 2 p)^8)] + (12 p - 
      12 p^2) #1 + (-12 p + 12 p^2) #1^2 + (-1 + 4 p - 4 p^2) #1^3 &,
  2]
```

For numerics this is an unnecessary nasty form and often generates small imaginary parts on the range where the value is actually real.

I'm particularly interested of the value when $0 \leq p \leq 1$. In this case I can use `ToRadicals` to ease `FullSimplify`ing the `Root`:

```
FullSimplify[ToRadicals@%, 0 <= p <= 1]
```

> $$\frac{2 \left(2 (p-1)
>    p+\sqrt{-(p-1)
>    p}\right)}{(1-2 p)^2}$$

Now, this is much more understandable and numerically neat. This feels to me a bit of a hack, though; I would be interested of hearing of a more generic method for this kind of root simplification with assumptions; clearly I can't expect `ToRadicals` to work for all polynomials. Also, I found out that `FullSimplify` with assumptions does nothing to the original `Root` object...

Comment: Did you include the constraint `0<=p<=1` in the minimization process?

Comment: @BobHanlon Yep, doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica often considers [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects as simpler forms since they can have a much lower [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html). For example,

```
sol = Solve[x^3 - 7 x + 2 == 0, x]

(* {{x -> (-9 + 2 I Sqrt[237])^(1/3)/3^(2/3) + 7/(3 (-9 + 2 I Sqrt[237]))^(
    1/3)}, {x -> -(((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-9 + 2 I Sqrt[237])^(1/3))/(
     2 3^(2/3))) - (7 (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/(
    2 (3 (-9 + 2 I Sqrt[237]))^(
     1/3))}, {x -> -(((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-9 + 2 I Sqrt[237])^(1/3))/(
     2 3^(2/3))) - (7 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/(2 (3 (-9 + 2 I Sqrt[237]))^(1/3))}} *)

sol2 = sol // FullSimplify

(* {{x -> Root[2 - 7 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {x -> Root[2 - 7 #1 + #1^3 &, 2]}, {x -> 
   Root[2 - 7 #1 + #1^3 &, 1]}} *)

LeafCount /@ {sol, sol2}

(* {187, 52} *)
```

To return to the radical form you would need to either use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) or a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

In your case, until the constraint on `p` is known, the `Root` object is simpler

```
expr = Root[
   1 + 2/(1 - 2 p)^4 - 3/(1 - 2 p)^2 - 4 p + 4 p^2 - 
     16 Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(-1 + 2 p)^8)] + (12 p - 
        12 p^2) #1 + (-12 p + 12 p^2) #1^2 + (-1 + 4 p - 4 p^2) #1^3 &, 2];

expr2 = expr // ToRadicals // FullSimplify

(* (p + I Sqrt[3]
     p + (1 - I Sqrt[3]) ((1 - 2 p)^4 Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(1 - 2 p)^8)])^(
    2/3) - 4 p (Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(-1 + 2 p)^8)] (-1 + 2 p)^4)^(1/3) + 
   p^2 (-1 - I Sqrt[3] + 
      4 (Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(-1 + 2 p)^8)] (-1 + 2 p)^4)^(1/3)))/((1 - 
     2 p)^2 ((1 - 2 p)^4 Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(1 - 2 p)^8)])^(1/3)) *)

expr3 = expr // ToRadicals // FullSimplify[#, 0 <= p <= 1] &

(* (2 (2 (-1 + p) p + Sqrt[-(-1 + p) p]))/(1 - 2 p)^2 *)

LeafCount /@ {expr, expr2, expr3}

(* {95, 184, 26} *)
```

Comment: The idea of changing `ComplexityFunction` is a good idea, but curiously enough even plain `LeafCount` makes simplification of the `Root` object take effectively forever, thus making this approach impractical when trying to avoid `ToRadicals`. I think this is pretty curious...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are basically looking for the region in p where the expression is real-valued. You can find this using Reduce. With exp equal to your expression,

```
reg = Reduce[exp>0]
0 < p < 1/2 || 1/2 < p < 1

FullSimplify[ToRadicals[exp], reg]
(2 (2 (-1 + p) p + Sqrt[-(-1 + p) p]))/(1 - 2 p)^2
```

returns your desired form.

Comment: I'm wishing to avoid using `ToRadicals` - although you can certainly ease finding the region with `Reduce`, or, say, `FunctionDomain`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike radical expressions, `Root` objects with exact coefficients resist the phenomenon of parasitic imaginary parts. Thus,

```
 Root[1 + 2/(1 - 2 p)^4 - 3/(1 - 2 p)^2 - 4 p + 4 p^2 - 
 16 Sqrt[-(((-1 + p)^3 p^3)/(-1 + 2 p)^8)] + (12 p - 
    12 p^2) #1 + (-12 p + 12 p^2) #1^2 + (-1 + 4 p - 
    4 p^2) #1^3 &, 2]] /. p -> Rationalize[pp, 0]
```

is purely real for 0<=pp<=1.